# Bringing the activity to front - I am losing the data

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

When I get a message I need to bring the activity to front. I use the following code:

```
public void BringToFront()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), getClass());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

When I get the activity on top the previous data is lost, even though the activity was not killed by the OS. Is there a way to get the activity back without losing the data or I need to recover the data anyway?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work. Your Activity is only active when it's in front. If it's not in front, it can't process so your method will never be called. An Activity should always save the data it wants to keep, either in onSaveInstanceState or when the data is changed. There's many ways to save data between activities. 
If you want your activity to be in front, you'll have to close all activities that are on top of it. If you need these activities again, you should have them save their data, and start them again with the new data.

I suggest you read the documentation on how Activities work....

Comment: This method is called explicitly when I get a message from other application. The code runs and shows me the activity but all fields are blank.

Comment: That's because a new copy of the activity is created by startActivity, which is placed on top of the stack. You could make your activity singleInstance, but really, this is not the way to build an Android app....

Answer (score 0):

Just use this method in your activity as per your situation. it will work.

```
protected void moveToFront() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) { // honeycomb
            final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            final List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

            for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) 
            {
                   Log.d("Executed app", "Application executed : " 
                           +recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString()
                           + "\t\t ID: "+recentTasks.get(i).id+"");  
                   // bring to front                
                   if (recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString().indexOf("Your app pckg name") > -1) {                     
                      activityManager.moveTaskToFront(recentTasks.get(i).id, ActivityManager.MOVE_TASK_WITH_HOME);

               }
        }
    }
}
```

Also you need to add below permission in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
```